# Get First Child of Every Parent with Same Class Name

Tags: jquery, foreach, parent, css-selectors

I am trying to vertically align a series of bubble text divs within their parent elements.

Simplified version of this nesting looks like this

```
<div class="bubble">
  <div class="bubble-inner">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bubble">
  <div class="bubble-inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using this jQuery to get my inner elements heights and I need to apply the margin to the parent element.

```
$('.bubble').each(function() {
    var rBubbleHeight = $('.bubble > .bubble-inner:first-child').outerHeight();
    var rbh = (405 - rBubbleHeight) / 2;
    $(this).css('margin-top',rbh);
});
```

The problem is that I only get the height of the first child of the first parent. When I use THIS I get null. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in each iteration, you are using the full selector (which will return only the first matched element), instead of looking inside the current `.bubble` alone.

Try this:

```
$('.bubble').each(function() {
    var rBubbleHeight = $(this).find('.bubble-inner:first-child').outerHeight();
    ...
});
```

Comment: @user2394359 - can you create a jsFiddle.net example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I had an error in the child element name actually. I apologize for that. This solution is correct. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('.bubble-inner').each(function() {
    var rbh = (405 - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2;
    $(this).css('margin-top', rbh);
});
```